# Why is Gaussian Processes Regression (GPR) suitable for time-series data?

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian

I'm just wondering that:  Compared with other methods (e.g., logistic regression, linear regression and support vector regression), why GPR is extremely suitable for Time-Series data? Why are the advantages of GPR? 
  Thank you for your help in advance~

Comment: What makes you think GPR is suitable for time series? A reference would be nice.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Someone mentioned that to me and it is true that GPR is more popular than other methods I mentioned above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: standard (Bayesian) regression methods usually treat all variables on the same footing, and thus don't incorporate information on the advance of the system. For example, a common assumption is that the probability density is separable `p(x_1, ... x_N) = p(x_1) * ... * p(x_N)`.

Methods like Hidden Markov Models (and also Gaussian Processes, if I remember right my reading of [Bishop's Machine Learning](http://www.amazon.de/Pattern-Recognition-Learning-Information-Statistics/dp/0387310738)), instead use a conditioned probability density (a Markov process), for example:

```
p(x_1, ... x_N) = p(x_N | x_{N-1}) * ... * p(x_2 |x_1) * p(x_1)
```

With this it becomes possible to incorporate some information on the evolution of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Neal revealed that many Bayesian regression models based on neural network converge to Gaussian Processes (GPs) in the limit of an innite network. To model time series, neural network is good choice, so GPR is also a good choice. Besides, a lot of time series satisfies the assumption of GPR, that is, all the observations are Gaussian.I think this maybe an important reason.

At last, GPR is very suitable for regression model actually, i think.

Neal, R. M. (1996) Bayesian Learning for Neural Networks, Lecture Notes in Statistics No. 118, New York: Springer-Verlag: blurb, associated references, associated software.